# android failed to parse PNG file

Tags: android, android-emulator

i have developed an app that runs perfectly fine on the simulator but when I try to run it on the phone, the app errors out stating java.io.FileNotException: res/drawable/divider_horizontal_dark.9.png

i thought the app was missing this file (probably android system file) so i found this file elsewhere on the web and placed it under drawable but in vain. the app still errors out with the same error as before.

any idea whats the problem here?

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="left|center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:paddingBottom="5px"
    android:paddingTop="5px" android:paddingLeft="5px" >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/linkImage" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/firstLineView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" android:textColor="#FFFF00" android:text="first line title"></TextView>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/secondLineView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="second line title" android:layout_marginLeft="10px" android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#0099CC"></TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the part of the code where the app crashes while loading.. you could see that there is no where i have used the file divider_horizontal_dark.9.png

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview,null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.firstLine = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstLineView);
                holder.secondLine = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.secondLineView);
                holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linkImage);
                //holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.star);
                holder.firstLine.setFocusable(false);
                holder.secondLine.setFocusable(false);
                holder.imageView.setFocusable(false);
                //holder.checkbox.setFocusable(false);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
.....
```

seems like they have fixed the issue
[http://code.google.com/p/transdroid/issues/detail?id=14](http://code.google.com/p/transdroid/issues/detail?id=144)

but i somehow dont get it

Comment: How are you trying to open it. How are we supposed to help without posting some code.

Comment: i am sorry but what part of the code should i post...since i am not calling that file anywhere, can you plz tell me what part of the code u want me to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an id for the resource instead of trying to open the file by giving the path to it (in the source code). There is plenty of Android documentation to explain how to do that...

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html

Comment: well...i have not used that file in my code...i have other files which i have placed in the drawable folder and the files are picked up fine. but this file i believe is fetched/created from the system and i have no control on that. i think it is the line seperator in the list view... any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the code you use that is failing ? That will help finding what the issue is... Based on the error, it really looks like you are trying to access the file through the path (which would explain why it may work with the emulator too).

Comment: i am sorry but what part of the code should i post...since i am not calling that file anywhere, can you plz tell me what part of the code u want me to post

Comment: You can start by the layout file where that image is used. Grep your source directory for "divider_horizontal_dark.9.png" and see where it is mentioned.

Comment: i just posted the code where the app crashes out convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview,null);
the xml is listview.xml